# Run reactJS client with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native, npm-install

I am .net developer.Previous developer used nodeJS and react for one project.I must complete that project.That project use nodeJS,and reactJS.I installed NodeJS in windows 8

I install packages(npm install) it worked well.But now I try to run-start project but it give error

When I write npm start it give that error

```
 Failed at the react-seed @0.0.13 start script node_env=development node dev-server .webpack/config
```

here is log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.14.20
3 info using node@v4.4.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart react-seed@0.0.13
6 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 info start react-seed@0.0.13
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info react-seed@0.0.13 Failed to exec start script
10 verbose stack Error: react-seed@0.0.13 start: `NODE_ENV=development node dev-server ./webpack/config`
10 verbose stack Exit status 1
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:214:16)
10 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
10 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
10 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
10 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
11 verbose pkgid react-seed@0.0.13
12 verbose cwd C:\nodeAQ
13 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
14 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
15 error node v4.4.1
16 error npm  v2.14.20
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 error react-seed@0.0.13 start: `NODE_ENV=development node dev-server ./webpack/config`
18 error Exit status 1
19 error Failed at the react-seed@0.0.13 start script 'NODE_ENV=development node dev-server ./webpack/config'.
19 error This is most likely a problem with the react-seed package,
19 error not with npm itself.
19 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
19 error     NODE_ENV=development node dev-server ./webpack/config
19 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
19 error     npm bugs react-seed
19 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
19 error
19 error     npm owner ls react-seed
19 error There is likely additional logging output above.
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: You might have to trick with package.json to get it running on windows: https://github.com/badsyntax/react-seed/issues/22

Comment: now it fixed error and but it give some other error like this http://i.hizliresim.com/6PNjPk.png

Comment: Did you try to do what the error message explicitly tells you to do? https://github.com/sass/node-sass